# os.path.abspath("..") returns "C://User//" which is false + __file__ is not defined --> execution from Spyder3 (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, relative-path, modularity

I want to develop a python application which is based on modularity. 
It is my first python application, so I try to sum up my situation as detailled as possible:

I am coding in Python for a few months. Now i am currently developing an application for statistics issues. Since I dont wan't to write my code into a single, endless .py-file , I intend to organize my application in single py files and related folders. So each py file is then related to a functionality which can be used by another .py file.

To give an example for my **application folder structure**:

My Directory structure is:

```
Notebook.ipynb
__init__.py

A/
      function1.py
      function2.py
      function3.py
      __init__.py

B/
      function4.py
      function5.py
      function6.py
      __init__.py

C/
      imp.csv
```

The application shall be executed from the notebook.ipynb and uses the functions. E.g:

```
Notebook.ipynb
     (uses) --> function1.py
          (uses) --> function4.py
               (imports) --> imp.csv
```

I have searched for ways here to realize that:
I found out that i could import modules (.py files) into other .py files.
Regarding to my example: function1.py would import function4.py from the sibling folder B. Due to the fact that the folder A and B are silbings, functionalities determining relative paths of a certain script would help me. But I got issues on using the most consulted ways of realizing that. I used:

```
__file__
```

> > throws the error "name **file** is not defined"

```
os.path.abspath("..") //
```

> > returns "C:/USERS" which is definetly not the parentfolder of the script I executed (real path is much deeper than that; something like C:USERS/name/folder1/folder2/applicationfolder/folderA)

**Remark:** I didn't run the whole script but (for testing purposes) the single statements in Spyder3 (Python3.6). My assumption here is that the issues are related to the execution of single statements.

### ---

> My questions are:
>
> - Am I correctly with my assumption?
> - If yes: How do I test the import of a .py file?
> - If no: what is the problem here?
> - Regarding the final application in the end. I need a statement that ensures that the relative path is given for the script where it is is
>     included and not the script which imports it and only uses its
>     containing functions. So regarding to my example again:   
>    When
>     Notebook.ipynb(uses)   --> function1.py
>    function1.py (uses)    -->
>     function4.py
>    function4.py (imports) --> 1.csv
>    
>                I want
>     to make sure that although notebook is the callee of the whole
>     application, the statements in function1.py and function4.py are not
>     returning the folder of Notebook.ipynb at runtime.
>     Because in the
>     end there would be issues to load the csv file from another folder than
>     function4.py.

MANY MANY THANKS IN ADVANCE!! :))

PS: I am also open minded for other suggestions that would help and work to structure my application source code

Comment: `abspath('..')` doesn't give you the path relative to the *location of the script*, it gives you the path relative to the current working directory of the process that runs the script. These are two different things.

Comment: With respect to `__file__` not working -- how exactly are you testing? Can you generate a [mcve] others can use to see the problem themselves? (Providing a MCVE that reproduces a specific, distinct problem in the shortest possible code is also a defense against being closed as "too broad").

Comment: It works perfectly for me, f/e, when I run `echo 'import os.path; print(os.path.abspath(__file__))' >test.py; python3.6 test.py` -- do you get an error with that same code? Just as I provided a one-line copy-and-pasteable example that shows (hopefully) that and how it works, can you provide a very short copy-and-pasteable example that shows how it breaks in your example or use case?

Comment: ...if you only have problems with `__file__` in Spyder, then that's an IDE issue, and I'd suggest asking a question scoped specifically to the IDE and how you're invoking your code within it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks! It is a Spyder "issue" and my assumption is right. When I run my script __file__ is working!